# How to put marker at bottom of map instead of center(by default) of map with zoom enabled in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

In live track app I want to animate camera above marker and want to put marker always at bottom in newLocationChanged.

If I am building CameraPosition without zoom, It works fine.

But with zoom also I need to achieve same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the screen boundaries to get the desired position:

[As per documentation:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en)

> getBounds()
>   Return Value:  LatLngBounds
>
> Returns the lat/lng bounds of the current viewport. If more than one copy of the world is visible, the bounds range in longitude from -180 to 180 degrees inclusive. If the map is not yet initialized (i.e. the mapType is still null), or center and zoom have not been set then the result is null or undefined.

Comment: is it in android or javascript?

Comment: Javascript... as far as I could tell from your "question", you have a WebView, in that, you have a canvas/div/whatever that queries the internet for an Google Maps object, and creates it... then, you add markers to it, then on `newLocationChanged`.... in that function, (most likely a javascript engine behind it), you get the bounds of the map, add both x coordinates and divide by two, to get the center of it, then move the marker..... google about it